# Laravel 5.7 - Different cookies on dev and production servers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

The Laravel application I set up is working flawlessly on my CentoS 7 dev server. Specifically: logging in and logging out with:

```
    php artisan make:auth
```

However, when I move it to my live server, the "logout" function stops working. I click my logout button in Chrome,

```
    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    @csrf
    </form>
```

it redirects to my login screen through my LoginController function,

```
    public function logout(Request $request) {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/login');
    }
```

but when I type in a URL that is supposed to be secure, that URL loads. If I refresh the page, *then* it actually logs me out.

In Firefox, nothing happens at all when when the logout button is clicked on the blade.

Also, it may be worth noting that in Chrome on my dev server, the cookie set for the page has an Expires/Max-Age of 2hours from now (today)

```
    2019-01-15....
```

which is correct.

In Chrome on my live server, the cookie Expires/Max-Age is

```
    1969-12-31....
```

Save for my APP_URL, database credentials and mail server, my .env files are identical. I have changed nothing else -just uploaded the files. The rest of the functionality on the site works perfect.

I have tried many different configurations and searches and still no luck. Thank you for reading this.

Comment: How did you install your application on your live server?

Comment: The server configurations and file paths are identical so all I did was upload my files to the live server. Laravel is not installed in the live server however.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out on my live server in my .htaccess file, I was modifying the Cache-Control settings:

```
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <FilesMatch ".(php)$">
            Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400"
        </FilesMatch>
    </IfModule>
```

Once I removed these lines, my Laravel app now works.